# How do I use Fields to automatically number sections using words?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I've got a document I'm trying to automate is MS Word. I've got section numbers that use the format code

`AUTONUM  \* Arabic`

but this results in section numberings that read:

`1.` `2.` etc.

How do I change the format code so that it reads

`FIRST:` `SECOND:` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need to add a CardText formatting switch to your field and use a [SEQ field](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields) instead.

I.e., your field should look like this:  `{ Seq MySeq \* CardText \* Upper }`:

Here is a link to [my writing on field switches](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Switch).

In brief...

> [image: screenshot from page showing switches]

*The AutoNum field automatically inserts the full stop/period at the end and does not work with the other switches.* Note that the colon is outside the field.

Here is a [temporary link to a document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pieu9kr2s1s7xn8/deleteme%20seq%20cardtext.docx?dl=0) with the field shown. If you select the field you could store it as an AutoText entry or a Formatted AutoCorrect entry for easy use. Here is a link to [my webpage on AutoText, AutoCorrect and Building Blocks](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm).

*All webpage links above are to my website. The one below is to Microsoft documentation.*

### Note from [documentation on AutoNum field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-autonum-field-de3ba1c9-8519-412e-aa5c-1f4b6ff0f244):

> Important:  This field is considered obsolete but is provided for
> compatibility with Microsoft Word 2000 or earlier versions. We
> recommend that you use the ListNum field instead of AutoNum when using
> versions of Word that are newer than Word 2016 for Windows or Mac,
> Word 2010, Word 2007, Word 2003, or Word 2002.

Unless there is a compelling reason, I recommend using the Seq field instead of ListNum or AutoNum.

Comment: Thank you for your well-written answer. However there is something about Seq that is not suited for my use-case. I am automating forms and my work as selected Doxsera/TheFormTool for this task. When I used AutoNum, hitting the 'fill' button would update the section numbers correctly even sections were removed conditionally by Doxsera. In my tests, Seq only updates when I manually hit F9, which is a problem since I am doing so many forms in one batch.

Also, could you tell me the name of whatever this programming language is so that I can refer to the canonical documentation? Thanks again!

Comment: It is not a programming language, exactly. It is Word fields. @macropod, who frequently contributes is an expert on that. You can find some of his tutorials pinned here: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/  Here is the basic documentation on fields: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-in-word-HA102110133.aspx Here is my unfinished page on fields: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm You can use a macro to update all fields or all seq fields in a document at one time. You can press Ctrl+A followed by F9 to update all fields in the body of a document.

Comment: You could also see if the ListNum field meets your needs. I do not use that field so can't say. I do not know if it responds to the Upper switch. https://support.microsoft.com/office/557541b1-abb2-4959-a9f2-401639c8ff82